# Spring data redis atomic integer variable key name

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis

I think I'm probably missing something big, but how do you do an atomic decrement on a given key using Spring Data redis?

The `RedisAtomicLong` and `RedisAtomicInteger` are bound to the key we specify while instantiating them.

How would I do an atomic decrement on any key of my choice?

Do I have to resort to multi-exec? In vanilla redis, i can atomically decrement any key without resorting to multi exec, by simple using the DECR command. Am I missing something here?

Thanks,
Richard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to decrement by dynamic keys you can do the following

```
// inject the actual template
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Integer> template; // This can be RedisTemplate<String, Long> also based on your need

// inject the template as ValueOperations
@Resource(name="redisTemplate")
private ValueOperations<String, Integer> valueOps;

public Integer decrement(String key) {
    return ((Long)valueOps.increment(key, -1l)).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Hi, But would this also not be possible with a simple StringRedisTemplate? I mean if all I have to do is increment by a negative value, then is it necessary to use an integer/long template?